# jquery not working properly from js file

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery script to count characters in a box

```
$('#myfield').keyup(function () {
    var left = 250 - $(this).val().length;
    if (left < 0) {
        left = 0;
    }
    $('#counter').text('put: ' + left);
});
```

If i put this code right after the field it works, but i want to externalize this to a js file.. so i copy this in a myscript.js
and then do this:

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="script/myscript.js"></script>
```

and it works... the problem is this call to myscript.js will only work if i declare it in that same spot after the field (which is at the bottom of the page).. but I want to include it at the top with all other js calls, if i do that, this won't work because I'll get a **"'null' is null or not an object"**.

So I tried enclosing it in document ready but even though I don't get an error nothing happens as in.. the function doesn't seem to be executed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//function here
});
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Did you include jquery in your html?

Comment: you should include your script after jquery

Comment: Yes, it's after jquery, jquery call is at the top of all the js calls

Comment: This seems to be impossible to debug without seeing the actual page. You need to upload it somewhere and share the link.

Comment: It depends on how your field is insterted in your document (native, or dynamically created), you can try replacing this $('$myfield').keyup(function () { by $(document).on('keyup',''#myfield',function () {

Comment: Any errors in the console? Can you repro this on jsFiddle?

Comment: Please paste you relevant piece of HTML...

Answer (score 1):

Your selector should be `$('#myfield')`, not `$('$myfield')`. And keep it in the document ready function.

---

***EDIT:***

Whether it's in an external JS file or in the same file shouldn't make any difference. The placement where that code is included *does* make a difference. I usually include all my JS scripts in the `<head>`. It should be wrapped in `$(function() { ... });` so that it doesn't execute before the DOM is loaded.

Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw6jS/). Notice that if you change the dropdown in the left frame between onDomready/onLoad/No wrap - head/No wrap - body, that changes whether or not the code works. If you set it to onDomready, the resulting code looks like this, which works:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#myfield').keyup(function () {
                var left = 250 - $(this).val().length;
                if (left < 0) {
                    left = 0;
                }
                $('#counter').text('put: ' + left);
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myfield">
        <p id="counter">put: 246</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that the fact that the JS code is directly in the head vs. being in an external JS file should make no difference for this example. If you replaced that `<script>` tag with an external include that had the same JS code, and left it in that same place, it would work just the same.

If this still doesn't work for you, then I suggest you make a jsFiddle of your own that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Yes, typo, corrected.. and it is already in the ready function, i re-wrote it for those that don't know that document ready is equivalent to "$(function() { "

Comment: "JS code is directly in the head vs. being in an external JS file" the problem is not internal vs external given that it works the same at the bottom, it is as you said whether i put the script call at the top or the bottom, the problem really is that putting it at the top with all the other js calls doesn't work even when putting it inside "ready". I can't seem to use that fiddle site, i get a 'Editor' is null or not an object

Comment: If even jsfiddle doesn't work I'm willing to guess that this is a problem on your browser, especially if you can't produce a demo of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is that when the code is in the HTML file it's executed after the field is rendered but when the code is in the file this is no longer the case.

So to fix this you should only set up your `keyup` event after you are sure the field has been inserted into the DOM.

Typically this is done by enclosing your code with handler for `$(document).ready()` event like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myfield').keyup(function () { // note #myfield instead of $myfield
        var left = 250 - $(this).val().length;
        if (left < 0) {
            left = 0;
        }
        $('#counter').text('put: ' + left);
    });
});
```

This will ensure that your code runs after all elements in the document have been rendered and you can interact with them.

You may want to take a look at jQuery documentation for [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) too.

Comment: That's what I said in my post, that code is exactly what i have and i get the error message i mentioned above... I guess I should be changing the "$(function() {
" with  "$(document).ready(function(){" since people doesn't seem to realize they are equivalent

Comment: Yes, I wasn't aware of that - sorry. Anyway do you have some line number and/or line contents related to `"'null' is null or not an object"` ? Otherwise we don't know which part of the code the error concerns...

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess it is #myfield
2. loading javascript at the bottom is always better
3. it is

   $(document).ready(function(){}

Comment: `$(function(){})` is the same thing unless the jQuery version is really old.

Comment: I tried $(document).ready(function(){} also first... same issue, and i read it is equivalent to $(function() anyways. I don't know about if it's better to include javascripts at the bottom, i've always seen them at the top, and i want to put it with all other calls, looks kind of strange to include it at the bottom on its own.

Comment: http://robertnyman.com/2008/04/23/where-to-include-javascript-files-in-a-document/